# how to find the height and width of an alphabet/letter

Tags: image, matlab, opencv

I want to find the height and width of a letter in generalize form but I dont know what algorithm should I apply so that I can find the height and width of any letter
I am using MATLAB as well as openCv. Anyone can suggest me anything how to approach

[image]

this image is my test image

my main task is to find the height and width of words say for eg "Football"

Comment: Hi, next time, please start working on the problem, write some code, and come with questions when you get stuck. Some may consider it unpolite to ask us write code from scratch

Comment: sometime I post code also but in this case I had no idea that's why I asked.My problem statement is something else, to get start I divided my problem statement now I will see the code and try to solve my actual problem statement

Answer (score 0):

You read the image with imread. You find the first instance where pixels are not white (255). You can sum rows and columns to get it quick, but you have to hide the add in the corner for this to work. You can then use the difference between y and x to get the width and height.

```
img = imread('unKDO.jpg');
% hide lettergenerator add
img(565:end,448:end) = 255;
% see when pixels are less than white
y(1) = find(mean(img) < 255,1);
y(2) = find(mean(img) < 255,1,'last');
x(1) = find(mean(img,2) < 255,1);
x(2) = find(mean(img,2) < 255,1,'last');
figure;
imshow(img)
hold on
plot(y(1),x(1),'*r')
plot(y(2),x(2),'*g')
```

Comment: thanx for code I will try this. Basically I wan to find the height and width of a word and pixel density of individual word. I will try my own and if I find any difficulty I will post.My aim is to detect font whether it is bold or not so for that I am thinking like this. If u have any other idea u can suggest